# findViewById returns null outside of main activity

Tags: android

I am writing my first android app. On the main activity I have some EditText fields, and when the submit button is pressed we go to a new activity where some calculation will be performed and update 2 TextViews.  For now I am just using hardcoded strings to understand the pattern and simplify the problem.

I have cleaned the project and ensured that I am referencing an ID that is within the view the activity is calling via setContentView.

ResultsActivity.java

```
public class ResultsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);

        TextView results = new TextView(this);
        results.setText("boom boom boom");
        this.setContentView(results);

        TextView winner = findViewById(R.id.pizza1Value);
        winner.setText("you win!");
        TextView loser = findViewById(R.id.pizza2Value);
        loser.setText("you lose!");
    }

}
```

activity_results.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/resultsActivityLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ResultsActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pizza2Value"
        android:layout_width="257dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pizza1Value" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pizza1Value"
        android:layout_width="257dp"
        android:layout_height="94dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.344" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am doing this same thing in MainActivity.java and it works fine.  Don't understand. Here is the stack trace

Stack trace:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pizzacalc.calc/com.pizzacalc.calc.ResultsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3251)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7045)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.pizzacalc.calc.ResultsActivity.onCreate(ResultsActivity.java:23)
```

Thank you!

Comment: MainActivity knows about the ID of the EditText, you have set the content view for that layout ```setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);```. The new Activity has a different layout correct? and different xml elements?

Comment: This is your problem: `this.setContentView(results);`.

Comment: The layout shown is the layout that pops up after main_activity.  I am accessing in the following manner:

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

EDIT:
Ok so the attempt at adding that new textView is causing the entirety of the XML to be replaced. That makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you are loading a new ContentView using  `this.setContentView(results);` , the `activity_results.xml` layout doesn´t exist anymore so you can´t get the references of `R.id.pizza1Value` and `R.id.pizza2Value`.

```
    ...
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);
    TextView results = new TextView(this);
    results.setText("boom boom boom");
    this.setContentView(results);  //*** Loading a new ContentView

    //This TextViews now are not contained in the view loaded!
    TextView winner = findViewById(R.id.pizza1Value);
    winner.setText("you win!");
    TextView loser = findViewById(R.id.pizza2Value);
    loser.setText("you lose!");
    ...
```